# Isn't there a predefined policy for IAM user access to AWS CodeDeploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy, aws-access-policy

To attach the policy mentioned in [step 2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/getting-started-provision-user.html) can't it be chosen from [policies](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?region=us-west-2#/policies)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any predefined policy that has the exact permissions listed in step 2 you mentioned above. In particularly to be able to access CodeDeploy you will need codedeploy full access policy ["codedeploy:*"] for which there exists a redefined policy "AWSCodeDeployFullAccess".